# How to continuously poll a file location based on message received

Tags: c#

My app receives messages from another system to indicate that a file has been posted in a folder and it then checks the folder to copy that file to another location. This works perfectly, but the file gets posted in the folder 20 minutes after the app gets the message. I'd like some help/ ideas on how I can create a delay without stopping the polling for each file.

Eg:

- 10:00am: Message received that 20180405_file1.pdf created
- 10:02am: Message received that 20180405_file2.pdf created
- 10:20am: check folder for 20180405_file1.pdf
- 10:22am: check folder for 20180405_ file2.pdf

I tried using `System.Thread.Timer`, and `Timespan`, but I don’t want the app to wait until first file is read and then process second file. I want it to be continuously processing other messages and read the files

Any help would be great

Comment: Is it an UWP or WPF or Winfrom app?

Comment: First thing id do, is fix this `but the file gets posted in the folder 20 minutes after the App gets the message.`. however failing that you could use `FileSyetemWatcher` and figure it out without the need of the message

Comment: This is a console application @Gaurang. I’ll give FileSystemWatcher a try

Comment: @EricDavid Please take a look at the answer below, I tried to give you a start. Let me know if still you need anything. I am sure it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MSDN:**

> FileSystemWatcher listens to the file system change notifications and
>   raises events when a directory, or file in a directory, changes.

Check [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) for more detail.

**What you need:**

```
FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher;

private void watch()
{
    fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    fileWatcher.Path = path;
    fileWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
    fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    WaitForFile(e.FullPath);

    //Copy files to another directory.
}

private void WaitForFile(string fullPath)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(fullPath))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

`OnCreated` will hit once I file is created but wait till it is written. There is no need for any timer as `FileSystemWatcher` will monitor new file creation.

You can use this only there is a particular folder where all your pdf files are generating after you get the message. If it is a common folder where there are other files too, you need to manage a list of pdf files name same you got from the message notification and then copied them based on condition in `OnCreated`.